# Windows Phone 7 Crash

Tags: windows-phone-7, crash

```
0   coredll.dll       xxx_RaiseException                                                                    19        
1        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                                          520892    
2        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                                          461967    
3        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                                          534468    
4                          TransitionStub                                                                        0         
5                          System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute                                        1916      
6                          System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll                                     284       
7                          System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute    764       
8                          System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute                       92        
9                          System.Linq.Queryable.Single                                                          444       
10                         LocalDatabaseSample.ViewModel.ToDoViewModel.DeleteAllToDoItem                         492       
11                         Emergency_Calls.EditMember.Delete_Click                                               180       
12                         Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarItemContainer.FireEventHandler                    292       
13                         Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarIconButton.ClickEvent                             88        
14                         Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarIconButtonContainer.ClickEvent                    60        
15                         Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBar.OnCommand                                        160       
16                         Microsoft.Phone.Shell.Interop.NativeCallbackInteropWrapper.OnCommand                  72        
17       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                                          507848    
18       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                                          509212    
19       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                                          692871
```

I cant understand what is causing the crash for some people...so I need a bit of help deciphering this.

Comment: You need to give us something more to work with - what is your code?  What are you doing when the exception happens?  A stack trace is very little use to us to work out any issues.

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the stack trace from the bottom up, looking for methods that are in your code: there will typically be system calls both at the top and the bottom of the trace which you need to interpret to give you context.

So, from the stack trace you can see that an application bar button was clicked and inside your code `LocalDatabaseSample.ViewModel.ToDoViewModel.DeleteAllToDoItem` there was an exception in a LINQ `.Single()` call.

This knowledge and knowing the exception type will help you, but as ZombieSheep says without the corresponding code it's difficult to help further.